# How to forward X over SSH to configure a desktop manager within cubic remotely

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, xorg, configuration, live-usb

I want to configure menus,windows,decorations,taskbars positions of the wanted desktop manager in real time inside cubic because I find it very comfortable to do while I'm inside cubic virtual environment. Below you see that I tried to enable the X forwarding through ssh because I wanted to configure a desktop manager like lxde or xfce from within cubic,but it failed. Do you have a workaround ?

within cubic :

```
root@cubic:~# /etc/init.d/ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                  sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
                                                                                       [fail]
root@cubic:~# ssh-keygen -A
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519 

root@cubic:~# /etc/init.d/ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                           [ OK ] 

root@cubic:~# adduser test
Adding user `test' ...
Adding new group `test' (1000) ...
Adding new user `test' (1000) with group `test' ...
Creating home directory `/home/test' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for test
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
 Full Name []: 
 Room Number []: 
 Work Phone []: 
 Home Phone []: 
 Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
```

on the host os :

```
ziomario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:~$ ssh -Y test@192.168.1.4 (host os IP Number)

The authenticity of host '192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4)' can't be established.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.4' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
test@192.168.1.4's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

it fails because the user test is not on the host os but on the cubic os,but 192.168.1.4 is the IP number of the
host os (cubic has none). If I do : ssh -Y test@192.168.1.4 inside cubic it will fails again because the user test is inside cubic,but the IP number is on the host os. If I create the user test on the host os and I will try to forward X using the host IP number and the user test,I will be able to configure xfce4 installed on the host os and that's not what I want.

Comment: I have the same request. Cubic is fantastic and just missing this functionality IMO. I want to configure favorites and connect to my WIFI, etc using the GUI as this persists upon boot of the live USB. I've tried terminal based solutions to no avail so far.

I'll try to look into this this weekend or sometime in the near future, would be great to figure this out.